# On what plane is 6912 Super Soarer based?

Tags: sets, model-identification

The set [6912](https://brickset.com/sets/6912-1/Super-Soarer), *Super Soarer*, features a yellow jet plane. My first thoughts were towards the [Harrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrier_Jump_Jet), but it has exhausts on the tail, which the Harrier doesn't have.

On what plane, if any, is it based?

[image: 6912 Super Soarer]
[image: 6912 Super Soarer bottom]

Comment: I think "inspired by" is a more accurate question - there are a number of aspects of this model that are "similar to" but not identical to real planes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would go for another British aircraft: [Sepecat Jaguar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SEPECAT_Jaguar)

It's twin-engine also.

[image: SEPECAT Jaguar]

[image: SEPECAT Jaguar on ground showing landing gear]

Answer (score 2):

The intakes, wing shapes and overall proportions look like a [Harrier Jump Jet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrier_Jump_Jet), but the model doesn't have the landing gear or under-wing armaments.

Similar overhead view of a Harrier:
[image]

Comment: The Harrier was the first one that came to my mind as well, based on this picture. But, as can be seen in ![this picture](http://www.1000steine.com/brickset/AdditionalImages/6912-1/6912_alt2.jpg), the _Super Soarer has exhausts on its tail, which the Harrier decidedly doesn't. I've added a picture showing this to the question.

Comment: The lack of armaments probably comes from the fact that LEGO tend [not to go in for "war" directly](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/291/56) as well as the fact that [someone else](http://www.character-online.com/products/Character-Building/HM-Armed-Forces/) owns the license for "HM Armed Forces" based construction toys