# Where are these minifigures from?

Tags: customization, minifigure-identification

In this image there are two army guys guarding:

[image]

But where were they bought? I'm curious to know where to get them myself.

Reply to Zhaph's Answer: (I don't have enough reputation.)

I'm well aware the minifigures and weapons are custom made, but I'm more curious where exactly to get the same pieces. I will probably find the weapons on some Brickarms seller (for me: Minifigforlife), but I don't seem to find the same minifigs. Any chance I could get either a seller or these or list of parts with sellers?

Comment: The minifigs probably aren't genuine Lego, although the rest might be. I recall reading there's something in Lego company's bylaws, saying that "the Lego man should never be enemical to mankind". Apparently this is why they don't make modern day weaponry for minifigs.

Answer (score 3):

The minifigures and the guns will be custom made. There are a number of sites that offer custom printed minifigs [in military uniforms](http://citizenbrick.com/collections/military), and [Brick Arms](http://brickarms.com) is a good place to start if you're after specific weapons.

The LEGO Group have a [policy of not creating "realistic" weapons](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/291/56), although both fantasy and futuristic are acceptable.