# Are there any army-related LEGO toys?

Tags: sets, history, lego-group

I don't recall ever seen a LEGO tank, a LEGO minifigure figure or any army-related LEGO sets.

I know that there are LEGO toys that imply some level of action/fighting, from police sets, knights, ninjas, etc. I have some LEGO toy guns (from pirate sets, etc.).

But I think I have never seen an army-related LEGO toy or set. The only ones I could mention are related to some franchises like Star Wars, Superheroes or similar.

Are there any army-related LEGO toys and if not if this a conscious decision from the LEGO group?

Comment: See also my answer to ["Does the LEGO Group condone war toys?"](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/294/56)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The LEGO Group does not directly create modern military sets.

A LEGO representative gave the following reason:

> **Are there any chances that Lego will ever start producing modern day warfare Lego, with tanks and helicopters and what not?**
>
> We have a strict policy regarding military models, and therefore, we do not produce tanks, helicopters, etc. While we always support the men and women who serve their country, we prefer to keep the play experiences we provide for children in the realm of fantasy.
>
> -- [Gizmodo - Everything You Always Wanted to Know About Lego](https://gizmodo.com/5019797/everything-you-always-wanted-to-know-about-lego)

There have been some sets that have been military-based though.

The [7595-1: Army Men on Patrol](https://brickset.com/sets/7595-1/Army-Men-on-Patrol) is based on characters from a movie series who are based a military-themed toy.

[image: 7595-1: Army Men on Patrol]

A number of [Indiana Jones sets](https://brickset.com/sets/theme-Indiana-Jones) have some military people and vehicles that in the movie are considered military vehicles. Notably missing though is the tank from the tank scene in Indiana Jones and The Last Crusade.

The [Dino Attack theme](https://brickset.com/sets/theme-Dino-Attack) (or [Dino 2010](https://brickset.com/sets/theme-Dino-2010) internationally) also has a tank and a helicopter modeled after military vehicles.

Answer (score 4):

LEGO has a policy that they won't make military sets (unless licensed, for ex. Indiana Jones) for several reasons:

1. Creative imagination for children
2. Debate of the "good" guys and "bad" guys
3. Neutrality (since Lego is sold worldwide)

For reference: [Youtube: Why doesn't Lego make military vehicles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4U1m-oqzUAo)

However, I know of several third party and other "compatible with leading brick" companies that produce products that can be played with LEGO.

Third-party:

- Brickmania
- Batisbrick
- Brickbrigade
- Custombricks.de
- Battlebrickcustom
- brickbattalion
- combatbrick
- mechanizedbrick
- modernbrickwarfare
- unitedbricks

Compatible with LEGO brands

- Cobi
- Mega Bloks
- BanBao
- best-lock
- kazi
- kreo
- oxford
- sluban
- taisheng
- woma

Comment: "Debate of the 'good' guys and 'bad' guys" - interesting however that they propose sets with policemen and criminals (bank robbers, etc) such as in the Lego City collection. Physical violence is also a dominant theme in the NinjaGo series. Maybe their stance regarding violence is that it is tolerated as long as it is not directly lethal?

Comment: Possibly. Another view could be that in the beginning, everyone(including the "bad" guys) had happy/positive faces in themes such as Ninjago and City. However, I noticed that recently, themes such as Ninjago and Nexo Knights had some pretty sinister faces on the villains. Change of policy perhaps?

Comment: @SamuelL. Proper villain faces have been a thing since at least the 90s Western sets.

Comment: @ Weckar E. Yes. I do note that. However, what I'm trying to express is that some of the latest villain faces(See nexo knights and ninjago for examples of these faces) dont seem to be as child-friendly as earlier faces

Answer (score 3):

One prominent exception regarding army-related toys is the [10024 Red Baron](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10024-1&name=Red%20Baron&category=%5BSculptures%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D), also interesting in the context of the bad-guys good-guys debate. Modern warfare is indeed a no-go topic for LEGO, as explained in other answers. Violence in general, however, is quite dominant in many LEGO themes.

[image: 10024 Red Baron]

As Tonny pointed out, the [10226 Sopwith Camel](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10226-1&name=Sopwith%20Camel&category=%5BSculptures%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) should be mentioned as well.

[image: 10226 Sopwith Camel]

Comment: There is also the Sopwith Camel bi-plane (set 10226) from the same era. Von Richthofen shot down several Sopwith Camels during his 80 kill career. His last  kill was actually a Sopwith Camel as well.

Comment: @Tonny You are right, but I guess that's about it with LEGO 20th century war equipment.

Answer (score 2):

There was a time when Lego did produce Lego mini figures of western U.S. soldiers in a western setting. On the belts of all the figures are the letters “US”. This may be the only series to include a US military element. These sets ran from  1996 to 2002.

Answer (score 2):

The most recent example is LEGO Technic [Bell-Boeing V-22 Osprey (42113)](https://brickset.com/sets/42113-1/Bell-Boeing-V-22-Osprey).

[image]

It was announced and had a limited distribution already before public launch when [LEGO pulled the plug](https://brickset.com/article/52715/official-technic-bell-boeing-v-22-osprey-cancelled) (emphasis is mine):

> The LEGO Technic Bell Boeing V-22 Osprey was designed to highlight the important role the aircraft plays in search and rescue efforts.

> While the set clearly depicts how a rescue version of the plane might look, **the aircraft is only used by the military**. We have a long-standing policy not to create sets which feature real military vehicles, so it has been decided not to proceed with the launch of this product.

Since LEGO decided not to recall already distributed sets small amount of these reached the secondary market.