# non-LEGO Tank, Marine Corps - Can anyone identify set?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, clone-brands

Can anyone identify this tank? I'm looking for instruction to this set. I also found a strange door.

[image: tank]
[image: door]

Comment: That tank doesn't look like anything LEGO would make. The frame of the door looks wider than what LEGO makes and the colours also look wrong, so I don't think any of that is LEGO.

Comment: Vaguely related: [Are there any army-related LEGO toys?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9016/are-there-any-army-related-lego-toys/) and [Does the LEGO Group condone war toys?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/291/does-the-lego-group-condone-war-toys/)

Answer (score 4):

The picture of the vehicle isn't very clear.  It appears to be dark green and missing several pieces.  This makes an already difficult to identify set nearly impossible unfortunately.  The dark green color and apparent military theme strongly suggest this isn't a Lego brand set, as already mentioned by Henrik.

What is left of the vehicle looks like some sort of APC or IAV possibly.  I spent some time searching and couldn't find building sets with the Marine Corps sticker on them.  It is very likely this was made by one of the **many** companies that make Lego compatible military sets, and even if we knew the exact set, it is highly unlikely that building instructions could be found.  To try to help you figure out what's missing on your set I've included a couple pictures to give you an idea of what your set *might* have looked like.

[image]
[image]

As for the door, very little can be determined from the picture.