# What plane is the Aviation Adventures set based off?

Tags: model-identification

The title states my question. I think it looks something like a Japanese Zero fighter, but it's slightly off.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is this model's design is meant to resemble a WWII style [warbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warbird), but probably not any specific model.

[LEGO has a pretty strict policy about creating army-related sets](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/9016/5853), and when they do they are usually fantasy-based.

> **Are there any chances that Lego will ever start producing modern day warfare Lego, with tanks and helicopters and what not?**
>
> We have a strict policy regarding military models, and therefore, we do not produce tanks, helicopters, etc. While we always support the men and women who serve their country, we prefer to keep the play experiences we provide for children in the realm of fantasy.
>
> -- [Gizmodo - Everything You Always Wanted to Know About Lego](https://gizmodo.com/5019797/everything-you-always-wanted-to-know-about-lego)

The most-modern military planes they have made so far are WWI models of Red Baron and Sopwith Camel.

For this reason, it would make sense that they would avoid making it look exactly like any specific military plane.