# Are all of these police minifigs from LEGO?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, minifigure-identification

While I'm glad LEGO is [taking a principled stand](https://www.vulture.com/2020/06/lego-pulls-advertising-for-police-toys-donates-usd4-million.html) on recent events, I've seen this set of police minifigs circulating on social media portraying the evolution of LEGO Police through time:

[image: police minifigs]

I don't have any trouble believing the 3 minifigs on the left are legitimate minifigs from LEGO sets, but the fourth one looks much more militaristic than I imagine LEGO would put into a set. Can anyone identify this minifig or confidently rule out it being a LEGO minifig? If anybody wants to identify the first three, that would be cool too.

My first guess was that the long gun was from [BrickArms](http://www.brickarms.com/modern.php), but I didn't see anything there that has a scope and a forward handgrip. Can you identify the assault rifle?

Comment: That 4th one is definitely not an official LEGO product. I'll probably leave to someone who can identify what it actually is to post an answer.

Comment: On a side note, [this is actually the first police set with minifigures](https://brickset.com/sets/659-1/Police-Patrol) although they are different from the modern minifig.

Comment: If you look closely at the second one, you'll see that it was roughly cropped out of some other photo with some not-very-good lighting.

Comment: Be aware that unofficial mods and customizations of official Lego figures is a thing. It's possible to take an official figure and add unofficial clothes/ gear/ weapons/ slogans... you can see how this could get out of control esp. currently, and that's before we even get to Photoshop.

Comment: A YMCA LEGO set.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As pointed out by others, the first three minifigures are genuine LEGO (with the second having perhaps a few custom accessories). The fourth is not a LEGO minifig. It may include some genuine LEGO elements (legs, hands, etc), but the militaristic accessories are not LEGO elements. This [appears to be](https://www.fishpond.ae/Toys/SWAT-Police-Officer-M4A1-Rifleman-Modern-Brick-Warfare-Custom-Minifigure-Modern-Brick-Warfare/0737534742907) a custom minifig sold at one time by Modern Brick Warfare.

[image: Modern Brick Warfare Rifleman]

Not only does LEGO not include guns in their City sets, they also have much better lighting for their minifig photos than this.

Comment: **100% Real LEGO™!** Obviously fake 

Comment: Oh! The "timeline" creator stole the minifig image from this site! That explains everything!

Comment: @mindstormsboi Indeed. I found it via Google's reverse image search.

Comment: @mindstormsboi the "!00% real LEGO" refers to the minifigure, not the accessories ;)

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid That's a very good point, but there's another point to make: It says "This is the perfect minifig to add to your city!" but if you made a giant Lego city with that minifig and put it in a brickvention, everyone's gonna shoot you dirty looks and you can guess what happens next. So who even knows if that info is true or not??

Comment: @mindstormsboi "The *minifigure* is in NEW condition and made with 100% Real LEGO! The weapons and fear are high quality and made to last" and "The M4A1 officer comes with: 1x Real LEGO minifigure 1x M4A1 assault rifle 1x tactical helmet [...] 1x tactical gas mask 1x tactical body armour 1x tactical belt with G17 pistol" - and you're buying it from a site that produces compatible weapons and armour. The base figure is legitimate, all accessories are custom made by the seller.

Comment: Minifigs can't even hold that kind of gun properly since their arms only rotate on one axis.  Even if it's spaced correctly to fit in both hands at once, he'd be aiming sideways all the time.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman to be fair, minifig's can't really hold the legitimate musket/rifles properly from the pirates range either, nor brooms and most other two handed accessories as the hands are angled as well.

Answer (score 13):

These are identified from left to right.

[Series 18 of Lego Minifigures](https://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-minifigures-series-18-complete-set-71021-18) has that first policeman. Here is [the exact minifigure](https://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-classic-police-officer-set-71021-8).

The second one appears to be from [Series 9 of Lego Minifigures](https://rebrickable.com/sets/71000-17/minifigures-series-9-complete/?inventory=1#parts). Here is [the exact minifigure](https://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-policeman-set-71000-6).

The third policeman appears to be [LEGO Policeman with Riot Helmet Minifigure](https://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-policeman-with-riot-helmet-minifigure) with a different head. The head might be [Minifigure, Head Male Black Eyebrows, Chin Dimple and Lopsided Grin Pattern - Hollow Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626cpb0857#T=C).

As Alexander O'Mara pointed out, the fourth one is *totally* not official Lego. It is likely [this guy](http://modernbrickwarfare.com/swat-riot-shield-officer/) and whoever made the timeline did not bother to think about the excessive military detail in this minifigure ([Lego doesn't even make military content anyways](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9016/are-there-any-army-related-lego-toys/9017#9017)).

---

<sub>Actually, the "timeline" is quite inaccurate. The first policeman being shown was actually released in 2018, however it is most likely a reference to the [very first policemen](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=cop014s#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) (which look almost identical). Sometimes I mix up the two minifigs by accident, and I suppose the same story goes here (or (s)he probably did it because there are not many good pics of the early police guys y'know). The second and third policemen being shown were released in the same year, 2013. And the fourth one is not even real Lego, so who even knows about when it was made??</sub>

Comment: Your link in the footnote goes to a firefighter, not a policeman. There were policemen at that time, too, really similar to the one in the timeline, like [this one](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=cop014s#T=S&O={%22iconly%22:0})

Comment: @AngewisnolongerproudofSO Actually you're right, the minifig from 621 is a better example.

Comment: The only weapons I've ever found in Lego are the ray guns in the space sets and the historic series (castle/pirate/etc.).

Comment: @Joshua - Quite a few of the licensed themes also have various styles of guns in - [LEGO Indiana Jones](https://brickset.com/sets/7197-1/Venice-Canal-Chase), Star Wars (although that might be covered by your ray guns), [Jurassic World](https://brickset.com/sets/theme-Jurassic-World) - see also "[Rifle](https://brickset.com/parts?query=rifle)" or "[Gun](https://brickset.com/parts?query=gun)".