# Why doesn't LEGO make minifig weapons?

Tags: minifigures

The title contains the entire question, nothing more can be added.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Otherwise the answer is a fairly straight forward, "LEGO makes quite a few Minifig accessories that are weapons, Including melee, ranged, medieval, futuristic, and modern styles."

Comment: See also: [Does the LEGO Group condone war toys?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/291/56)

Answer (score 3):

The Lego Group has a policy of not producing modern looking weapon accessories.

If what you are looking for are 20th century style weapon accessories for mini figures you will need to look to non-Lego third party vendors.

Comment: Lego has made *tons* of Age of Sail flintlock muskets, cavalry cutlasses, Wild West six-shooters, medieval crossbows, jousting lances, katana, battle-axes, and obviously sci-fi weapons. Some of those can be reasonably re-imagined as modern weapons, if you wish.